# Blink text N times

Tags: css

I'm working on a trading dashboard and I have a "the last update..." text, which should blink twice at the beginning and then stays static. Also, there's a loader that lasts 200ms. Appreciate any help!

```css
.BlinkingUpdate{
    margin-bottom: 0;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-right: 15px;
    animation: blinker 1.5s; 
}

@keyframes blinker {   
     50% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
 }
```

```html
<p class="BlinkingUpdate">Last refresh happened sunday</p>
```

Comment: You have a typo: Missing `<span>`

Answer (score 2):

Use [animation **iteration count**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-iteration-count) (set it to `2`)

```css
.BlinkingUpdate{
  animation: blinker 1.5s 2; 
}

@keyframes blinker {   
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="BlinkingUpdate">Last refresh happened sunday</p>
```

Just to remember, the [`animation` shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation) property consists of:
*duration | easing-function | delay |
**iteration-count** | direction | fill-mode | play-state*

Therefore, if you want to add an **initial 200ms delay** - set it before the iteration-count:

```css
.BlinkingUpdate {
  animation: blinker 1.5s 0.2s 2;
}

@keyframes blinker {
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="BlinkingUpdate">Last refresh happened sunday</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Play more with the `%` in animation also you can change the time

```css
.BlinkingUpdate{
    margin-bottom: 0;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-right: 15px;
    animation: blinker 2s; 
}

@keyframes blinker {   
     25% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
50%{
      opacity:1;
   }
100%{
      opacity:0;
    }
 }
```

```html
<p class="BlinkingUpdate">Last refresh happened sunday</span></p>
```